# TreeNodeCollection воскрешает удаляемые Node'ы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
static class TreeNodeCollectionExtensoions
{
    public static void Swap(this TreeNodeCollection list, int indexA, int indexB)
    {
        int min = Math.Min(indexA, indexB); //115
        int max = Math.Max(indexA, indexB); //116
        if (indexA >= 0 && indexB >= 0) //проверяю корректность
        {
            TreeNode tmpA = list[indexA]; //помещаю ноды в буфер
            TreeNode tmpB = list[indexB]; //помещаю ноды в буфер
            bool AisMax = tmpA.Index == max; //116
            //сейчас TreeNodeCollection.Count == 117 (max == 116)
            list.RemoveAt(max); //удаляю сначала ту, что выше индексом
            //отрабатывается корректно, Count == 116 (max == 115), нужная Node удалена
            list.RemoveAt(min); //потом ту, что ниже индексом
            //удаление элемента по индексу происходит корректно,
            //, НО, та нода что была удалена через list.RemoveAt(max)
            // каким-то образом вернулась
            if (AisMax) //ищу последнюю
            {
                list.Insert(min, tmpA); // <-- System.ArgumentException:
                // "Невозможно добавить или вставить элемент 'menu116' в несколько позиций.
                // Сначала удалите его из текущей позиции или создайте его копию.
                list.Insert(max, tmpB);
            }
            else
            {
                list.Insert(min, tmpB);
                list.Insert(max, tmpA);
            }
        }
        //list[indexA] = list[indexB];
        //list[indexB] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Использую так:
treeNodeCollection.Swap(116, 115);
Ноды:
Node0
Node1
...
Node115
Node116

Воспроизводимость ошибки не очень хорошая, на одних коллекциях всё отлично, на других - нода восстанавливается самопроизвольно. Никаких параллельных потоков, работающих с коллекцией - нет.

Почему нода сама восстанавливается?
Как это исправить?

Comment: Потестил. Такая ошибка возникает, если в метод передать одинаковые индексы. Следует добавить в начало `if (indexA == indexB) return;`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хорошо, да действительно проверять это тоже стоит. Но индексы в моём случае не одинаковые. Залез в исходники фреймворка - файл ``TreeNode.cs`` строка ``1810 treeView = null;`` последняя в вызове RemoveAt - отрабатывается, как элемент восстанавливается?...

Comment: Winforms?......

Comment: @aepot он самый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TreeNode tmpA = list[indexA];
if (tmpA.TreeView.SelectedNode == tmpA)
    tmpA.TreeView.SelectedNode = null;
TreeNode tmpB = list[indexB];
if (tmpB.TreeView.SelectedNode == tmpB)
    tmpB.TreeView.SelectedNode = null;
```

Понял в чём косяк, элемент висел в SelectedNode, и TreeView его восстанавливал.
Почему в большинстве других случаев это не воспроизводится - загадка.
Хотя это забавно, т.к. Selected на элементе остаётся, могу только предположить что когда он возвращается в список - TreeView смотрит на него и восстанавливает SelectedNode...

Если у кого есть дополнительные мысли на этот счёт или всё это не надёжно - прошу прокомментировать.